# I have to find the names of the employees who have never worked for two consecutive days in the same center

Tags: mysql

I have to create a code, in sql, that allows me to find the id of the employees who haven't worked for two days in a row
My data has this structure:

| id_emp | date | id_center |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2020-12-11 | 0045 |
| 0001 | 2020-12-12 | 0045 |
| 0001 | 2020-12-13 | 0045 |
| 0002 | 2020-12-11 | 0047 |
| 0002 | 2020-12-13 | 0047 |
| 0003 | 2020-12-11 | 0043 |
| 0003 | 2020-12-12 | 0043 |
| ... | ... | ... |

The table to be returned must be structured like this:

| id_emp |
| --- |
| 0002 |

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id_emp, DATEDIFF(date, LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY id_emp, id_center ORDER BY date)) = 1 consecutive
    FROM src_table
),
SELECT id_emp
FROM cte
GROUP BY id_emp
HAVING NOT SUM(consecutive)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct id_emp
from mystery_table_name
where id_emp not in (
    select distinct id_emp
    from mystery_table_name a
    join mystery_table_name b on b.id_emp=a.id_emp and b.id_center=a.id_center and b.date=a.date + interval 1 day
)
```

Though looking for employees in your table of who worked when and where is strange, and will leave out employees who have never worked.  Surely you have an employee table.

If on mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2 or better, Akina's answer may be more performant, especially if you do not have an `(id_emp,id_center,date)` index.